# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS randomly restarts

Tags: 20.04, crash, restart

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The computer crashes and restarts several times a day. I can't find the reason. Please help

Details of my computer:

```
System:    Host: xxx Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: Z170-P v: Rev X.0x serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 3805 date: 05/16/2018 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-6600K bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] driver: nvidia v: 510.47.03 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa tty: N/A 
           OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 510.47.03 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-3: SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries SC2 USB Headset type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-28-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp6s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 70:4d:7b:65:83:0c 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 2.28 TiB used: 15.72 GiB (0.7%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: GOODRAM model: N/A size: 223.57 GiB 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD7500BPVT-80HXZT3 size: 698.64 GiB 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Samsung model: HD103SI size: 931.51 GiB 
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: SSDPR-CX400-512 size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 28.04 GiB used: 12.41 GiB (44.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdd5 
           ID-2: /home size: 62.51 GiB used: 3.31 GiB (5.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdd7 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.63 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sdd6 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: nvidia temp: 57 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 28% 
Info:      Processes: 300 Uptime: 19m Memory: 15.57 GiB used: 2.12 GiB (13.6%)
```

Comment: Is your SSD reliable? I've never heard of the brand and when I search the model number, the manufacturer's website doesn't even have a valid SSL certificate, which to me is a red flag.  Also, did you follow an outdated guide to install Ubuntu? With so much hard disk space available, it's strange to only allocate on 28GB when the bare minimum is 25GB. Also it's no longer recommended to create a swap partition or a home partition. It shows that you did not install Ubuntu with the default options. It would also help to know what you did *after* installation, especially software outside of repos.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
My SSD is GOODRAM CX400 SATA III SSD. I separated 100GB from this disk and created 3 partitions manually. 30GB for /, 8GB for / swap, and the rest for / home. I installed ubuntu from the youtube tutorial. I installed a few applications: spotify, conky, nvidia driver 510, ulauncher, that's all. Where can I find information in the logs about what caused the computer restart? I am using windows 10. Ubuntu is the second operating system.

Comment: I'm only aware of one [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). I don't agree that your partition scheme is appropriate.You don't have enough room in comments to provide the details you need to add to understand what you did after installation.Any software you installed from the software center without adding additional sources should be fine. But you should add complete details about anything you did that isnt that. For example, if you added sources, PPA, or manually compiled software, yoh could have broken something. Edit your question and include all details.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I have installed so I have reinstalled the system. I've not installed any application. I am waiting for the first crash.

Comment: The computer has restarted again. I was running the spotify app and listening to music.

Comment: How did you install Spotify? What else did you install, and how (for each application)? And what else did you do to configure the device after installation?  Are you certain that the SSD and other hardware are reliable?

Comment: I've installed spotify from the ubuntu software. I did not install anything else. I tested the RAM today and there are no errors. This is a new disk but it will scan it for bad sectors.

Comment: I've checked my disk and it doesn't have bad sectors.

Comment: Why do you have "Legacy" enabled in UEFI ("BIOS")? Have you installed in Legacy mode? WHY? That may well be the beginning of your troubles although failing hardware is much more likely given its age.

Comment: It's a default setting in bios.